# Gauge.writemessage() does not included in html-report

Tags: automation, getgauge

We are using Gauge for automation testing. 
Please find below version for Gauge, html-report, xml-report, java

C:\Users\jay>gauge -v
Gauge version: 0.7.0

### Plugins

html-report (1.1.0)
java (0.3.3)
xml-report (0.1.1)

My scenario is

[image]

And my step implementation is

[image]

When I run my spec. It should include "Hello Jay Here" text into HTML-REPORT.
However, it haven't included.
Please find below screen shot for the same.

[image]

I have tried to change the html-report plugin version to 3. But after changing the version of a plugin, html-report stops generating.

So, Anyone knows what should I do to get it included?

Thanks,
Jay Patel

Comment: You are on a very old version of Gauge + html-report. Please upgrade gauge (hint: run `gauge --check-updates`).

Comment: I have upgraded and now problem has resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An update may resolve the issue. Please follow the steps below

Download the latest report zip file from the below location[Please search for the download page in google if the below link doesn't work]

https://github.com/getgauge/html-report/releases

Move this downloaded zip to your project directory where you have the **reports** folder

Open cmd and navigate to your project directory and execute the below command. Please change the downloaded file name in the command.

gauge install html-report --file **html-report-4.0.6-windows.x86_64.zip**

This may resolve the issue. Please let me know if this solution doesn't work. It worked for me as I was using the Boilerplate code and it had older version of report plugin